# How can I get data of last week or last month in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

Say, I have a JSON data

```
[
    {
        "transaction": "34",
        "date": "Mar 12 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "21",
        "date": "Mar 12 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "40",
        "date": "Mar 13 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "40",
        "date": "Mar 14 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }

]
```

There may be several transactions in one day. How can I get the most recent one week's or month's transaction records from this JSON data?

Comment: First of all you json does not look correct, I suppose it should be an array []. Second, you need to iterate through items in that array and do apply the logic. You can use `reduce` method of an array.

Comment: Your `JSON` is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

Checkout below

Data seems not valid, i changed it from Object to Array

I added code for Last one month Data,Last One week

```js
var data = [{
        "transaction": "34",
        "date": "Apr 12 2017 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "21",
        "date": "Apr 12 2017 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "40",
        "date": "Mar 15 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "50",
        "date": "Jan 13 2017 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "40",
        "date": "Mar 13 2017 10:00:00 AM"
    }, {
        "transaction": "40",
        "date": "Mar 14 2016 10:00:00 AM"
    }];

//It will return dates diff in no. if months
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth(); 
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
//It will gets the last month date
function getLastMonth(){
var x = new Date();
  x.setDate(1);
  x.setMonth(x.getMonth()-1);
  return x;
}
var prevMonthDate = getLastMonth();
var lastMonthData = data.filter(function(v){
 return monthDiff(new Date(v.date),prevMonthDate) < 1;
});

//This is the data for last one Month
console.log(lastMonthData);

//It will return dates diff in no. if Weeks
function weekDiff(d1,d2){
var dif = Math.round(d1-d2);
return Math.ceil(dif/1000/60/60/24/7);
}
//It will gets the last week date
function getLastWeek(){
    var today = new Date();
    var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
    return lastWeek ;
}
var prevWeekDate = getLastWeek();
var lastWeekData = data.filter(function(v){
 return weekDiff(new Date(v.date),prevWeekDate) == 1;
});
//This is the data for last one Week
console.log(lastWeekData);
```

**[Working example in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/h2bo9m73/1/)**

Comment: Next time, before you answer, please ask the OP to show their own work. It's not good to answer poorly asked questions.

Comment: Sure @evutionxbox

Comment: It's nothing against you. I just find it encourages a "gimme my code" attitude.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you for pointing this out for me. I'm just starting out and struggling with these algorithms. It's a bit ahead of me right now. Next time I'll come up with a solution at least.